# Rendering A List of Dictionaries in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following model in my django project (the objects are basically a list of dictionaries):

```
  def bill_sum(request):      
     titles = Summary.objects.values('title')
     summary = Summary.objects.values('summary')
     summary_text = Summary.objects.values('summary_text')
     action_date = Summary.objects.values('action_date')
     action_desc = Summary.objects.values('action_desc')
     context = {'title':titles,
  'summary':summary,
  'summary_text':summary_text,
  'action_date': action_date,
  'action_desc':action_desc,
}
      return render(request,'billsummary.html',context)
```

In my template I can generate a list of titles by the following html code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>
    {% for t in title %}
        <h1>{{t.title}}</h1>

    {% endfor %}


  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to add additional information (such as a loop for all the summary objects, nothing renders except the titles. What am I missing? How do I render a list of dictionaries (i.e. a Json data file) from my views into a template?

What I want to do is something like the following in the template:

```
    {% for c in context %}
<h1>c.title</h1>>

<h2>c.summary</h2>
<p>c.action_date</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
summaries = Summary.objects.values('title', 'summary', 'summary_text', 'action_date', 'action_desc')

return render(request,'billsummary.html',context={'summaries': summaries})
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for t in summaries %}
    <h1>{{t.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{t.summary}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

It will hit the database only only one time and will be perfect for your case

Comment: Worked perfectly. It renders each individual dictionary in the view now.

Comment: But there is no need to use values here at all. Just get the objects and pass them to the template.

Comment: Values() ensures that the query will only select those fields instead of all the fields in the table so it will be faster